# ng-app not getting called in SweetAlert html, but works fine in html body

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, sweetalert, ng-controller

I can successfully insert a bootstrap table inside a SweetAlert but when I use ng-app or ng-repeat to populate some data inside the table's rows, ng-app doesn't get called. If I populate the table outside the SweetAlert (somewhere in the body...), I can see that ng-app gets called. Here's how I populate my table in the body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module("items", []);
        app.controller("controller", function($scope) {
            $scope.items = the_data;
            console.log("called");
        });
    </script>

<div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="card">
           <div class="content">
               <table class="table table-striped">
                   <thead>
                       <th style="text-align: center">Items</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center">Price</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center">No.</th>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody ng-app="items" ng-controller="controller">
                       <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
                        <td align="center">{{item.name}}</td>
                        <td align="center">{{ item.price }}</td>
                        <td align="center">{{ item.number_of_items }}</td>
                       </tr>
                   </tbody>
               </table>
               </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

The code above will populate `the_data` inside the table. Now when I copy the same exact code and insert it inside swal, it only populates the table but doesn't populate `the_data`. Here's my code for populating the table inside swal:

```
    $().ready(function(){
      window.operateEvents = {
         'click .view': function (e, value, row, index) {
            var app = angular.module("items", []);
            app.controller("controller", function($scope) {
               console.log("called");
               $scope.items = the_data;
            });
                        swal({
                            title: 'Purchase details',
                            type: 'info',
                            html: '<div class="col-md-3"><div class="card"><div class="content"><table class="table table-striped"><thead><th style="text-align: center">Items</th><th style="text-align: center">Price</th><th style="text-align: center">No.</th></thead><tbody ng-app="items" ng-controller="controller"><tr ng-repeat="item in items"><td align="center">{{item.name}}</td><td align="center">{{ item.price }}</td><td align="center">{{ item.number_of_items }}</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div>',
                            showCloseButton: true,
                            showCancelButton: true,
                            confirmButtonText:'Done',
                        });
         }
      }
    });
```

Here's how the SweetAlert populates the table:
[image]

In the method above, `console.log("called")` is not being called, therefor I assume ng-app was never called in the first place. As you can see, apart from `the_data` not being populated in the rows, the buttons are positioned in the wrong place too. I would appreciate it if someone can explain either 1) why ng-app is not being called? 2) why are the buttons positioned behind the table instead of under the table (the buttons can't be clicked when the table is visible)?

A sample code would be very helpful as I am a beginner in HTML.

Comment: Why are you initialize `items` module in `script` tag?

Comment: The AngularJS initialization process is explained in [AngularJS Developer Guide - Bootstrap (Automatic Initialization)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#automatic-initialization).

Comment: @Leguest I'm not sure what where else to initialize it. Could you explain a bit more please?

Comment: @georgeawg Angular is already automatically initilized in the page but it's still not working...

Comment: Show your other code, why even need second ng-app?

Comment: HTML with AngularJS directives and bindings need to be compiled with the [$compile service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) for those bindings and directives to work. The SweetAlert library adds HTML to the DOM without doing a $compile and is not suitable for doing what you want.

Comment: SweetAlerts are a form of modal window. Use modals sparingly because they are interruptive. Their sudden appearance forces users to stop their current task and focus on the dialog content. Not every choice, setting, or detail warrants interruption. Alternatives to dialogs include menus or inline expansion, both of which maintain the current context.

Comment: @georgeawg Very well explained. It sounds like this is the method I should be using but after some research, I am having some trouble with compiling. Could you please post an example as the answer and I'll mark it as correct if it works!

Answer (score 0):

So I finally managed to solve this problem and I hope this will benefit others in the future. Since I ultimately needed ng-repeat to work to populate rows and repeat the process, I decided to write the following code to populate the data inside `<tBody>`:

```
var data2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < row[4].length; i++) {
    data2.push('<tr>',('<td align="center">' + data.name + '</td>'),('<td align="center">' + data.price + '</td>'),('<td align="center">' + data.number_of_items + '</td>'),'</tr>');
}
function htmlTable() {
 return ['<div class="col-md-3">',
  '<div class="card">',
   '<div class="content">',
    '<table class="table table-striped">',
     '<thead>',
      '<th style="text-align: center">Items</th>',
      '<th style="text-align: center">Price</th>',
      '<th style="text-align: center">No.</th>',
     '</thead>',
    '<tbody>',
     data2.join(''),
    '</tbody>',
   '</table>',
  '</div>',
 '</div>',
'</div>'].join('');
}
swal({
  title: 'Purchase details',
  type: 'info',
  html: htmlTable,
  showCloseButton: true,
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonText:'Done',
});
```

I would also like to note that I wasn't able to move the buttons under the table. They are still positioned where they appear in the provided picture, but the table doesn't interfere with it. instead, it narrows down the table, making it smaller. I will post a solution under this answer if I find one.

Comment: All solved! last thing I forgot was that I set col-m-3. I changed it to col-md-9 and it worked better. the buttons appear under the table.